# Change category order in barplot

Tags: bar-chart

I have data in pandas df like this {range: 0.08, Category: 'Unstable', Value: 22} but I only have the second category in one range and when I try to reorder the chart so "nestabilní" is on top "hue_order"= ['Nestabilní','Stabilní'], the value 22 of the chart disappears.

[with hue order ['Stabilní','Nestabilní']](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYWiH.png)
[with hue order ['Nestabilní','Stabilní'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waGRa.png)

```
ax = sns.barplot(x='range', y='Fitness', data=df,   hue='stable',hue_order=['Stabilní','Nestabilní'],
                palette='Set1', dodge=False, saturation=1)

sns.despine()
ax.grid()
ax.set_axisbelow(True)
plt.xlabel('Validační přesnost')
plt.ylabel('Počet funkcí')
plt.legend(title='')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.xticks(range(0, 51, 10), [f"{i/50:.1f}" for i in range(0, 51, 10)])
# plt.legend(title='')
plt.show()
```

I want to change order of plots so Nestabilní show on top of Stabilní bar